# How do 4x4 rotation and position matrix work (Cframes)

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation

Ok, so I am writing a raymarching program in OpenGL but I am having a hard time understanding what a Cframe is.

This is the code that generates the camera position and rotation

```
 vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy - 0.5 * iResolution.xy) / iResolution.y;

 vec3 camPos = vec3(5, 1, 1);
 vec3 camViewDir = normalize(vec3(uv.xy, 1));
```

but I want to abstract this into a Cframe and then pass the Cframe into the shader. The only problem is I am trying to figure out why there 9 numbers that are used for the rotation. Which ones do I use?

Comment: "Cframe" isn't a term OpenGL uses anywhere, and it is not a universally used term in computer graphics either. It most likely stands for "coordinate frame", which actually means "coordinate system" or "frame of reference". But what exactly  "these 9 numbers" mean - which 9 numbers? -  can be any encoding for some transformations. Your question is totally unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this form but what I mean is how do I rotate camPos using a rotational matrix? - - there are 3 formulas for a rotational matrix which one do I use?